# How to disable missing XML doc warnings only for enum fields?

Tags: c#, warnings, compiler-warnings, editorconfig

I appreciate `CS1591` and I would like to have it in my project, but I don't want it to trigger on undocumented `enum` fields. Is there a way to turn it off just for that while leaving all other cases?

For instance, in the following

```
public enum E
{
   Field,
}
```

I would get a warning only for missing XML for `E`, but not for `Field`.